# How to set list of object as data source for menu asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to take a list of an object that I programmed and set it as menu's datasource. How can I do it?

I tried this:

```
HTML:
<asp:Menu ID="Menu3" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticDisplayLevels="2" Font-Bold="True" Width="100%" 
CssClass="menu" IncludeStyleBlock="false"
EnableViewState="false" OnMenuItemClick="Menu3_MenuItemClick" />

CODE BEHIND:
 public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
    {
        private Categories categories;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client = new MyServiceClient();
            categories = client.SelectAllCategories(); //list with data from DB
            Menu3.DataSource = categories; //makes an eror
        }
    }
```

The eror that I get:

> Exepction User-Unhandled:
>
> > System.InvalidOperationException: HierarchicalDataBoundControl only
> >     accepts data sources that implement IHierarchicalDataSource or
> >     IHierarchicalEnumerable.

Comment: Where does `categories` come from? What is the complete exception detail?

Comment: copied the wrong code. check the new code

Comment: OK, but you should always include full exception details. "*makes an error*" is not enough to go on.

Comment: Sorry! First time asking here :) Just added the eror that i get!

Comment: I've never used an IHierarchicalEnumerable but that looks like a fine google term. Whatever `SelectAllCategories` returns does not implement that interface.

Comment: @Sabakakado Check this article for populating asp menu control 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11906/Populating-Menu-Control-in-ASP-NET-2-0-Using-Diffe